# Why does df.to_pickle() return an error, while df.to_excel() does work fine

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pickle

When I try to pickle a dataframe, I get an error:

```
df.to_pickle(r"C:\Users\TomCruise\workspace")
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\TomCruise\\workspace'
```

The folder called "workspace" is my current workspace. If I try `df.to_excel("file name.xlsx")` a file is correctly stored in the folder "workspace" with path C:\Users\TomCruise\Workspace.

Why does to_pickle return an error stating it does not have the permission to access the folder in the path, when to_excel works perfectly fine?

Comment: `C:\Users\TomCruise\workspace` is most likely the name of a directory. `to_pickle` (same as `to_excel`) expects a filename (potentially with path)

Comment: Indeed the filename method works. However, the documentation states a path should be specified.

Comment: Yes, the path to a file. Not the path to a directory where the file should be placed, without knowing what the file should be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add the file extention

```
df.to_pickle(r"C:\Users\TomCruise\workspace\filename.pkl")
```

Comment: So I just found out that `to_pickle("File name.pkl")` does work, even though the documentation states the path should be specified

Comment: The path is implicit. It is pointing to your current directory which is 'workspace' just like your excel example.